# Issue with hovering over a button in JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Paint, Inc.</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="sideNav">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script src="canvas.js"></script>
    <button id="clear" title="Clear">X</button>
    <section id="leftBumper"></section>
    
    <section id="colorChoice">
        <input id="color" type="color" value="#000000" />
        <label id="colorLabel" for="color">Color</label>
    </section>

    <section id="strokeWeightChoice">
        <input id="strokeWeight" type="range" min="1" max="51" step="5" value="1" list="tickmarks">
        <label for="strokeWeight">Thickness</label>
        <datalist id="tickmarks">
            <option value="1"></option>
            <option value="6"></option>
            <option value="11"></option>
            <option value="16"></option>
            <option value="21"></option>
            <option value="26"></option>
            <option value="31"></option>
            <option value="36"></option>
            <option value="41"></option>
            <option value="46"></option>
            <option value="51"></option>
        </datalist>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas {
    border: 0.0001px solid white;
}

html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#clear {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 30px;
    background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.32);
    border-width: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: red;
}

#clear:hover {
    transition: 0.4s;
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#clear:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#colorChoice {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.5rem;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#colorChoice:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#strokeWeightChoice {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3rem;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#strokeWeight {
    width: 200px;
}
```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const color = document.querySelector("#color");
    const strokeWeight = document.querySelector("#strokeWeight");
    //variables
    const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear");
  
    let painting = false;
  
    function startPosition(e) {
      painting = true;
      draw(e);
    }
    function finishedPosition() {
      painting = false;
      ctx.beginPath();
    }
  
    function draw(e) {
      if (!painting) return;
      ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
  
    function changeColor(e) {
      const color = e.target.value;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    }

    function changeStrokeWeight(e) {
        const strokeWeight = e.target.value;
        ctx.lineWidth = strokeWeight;
    }

  
    //Event listeners
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  
    color.addEventListener("input", changeColor);
    strokeWeight.addEventListener("input", changeStrokeWeight);
  
    //Buttons
    clearButton.addEventListener("click", clearCanvas);
  
    function clearCanvas() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
});
  
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
function resizeCanvas() {
    //Resizing
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
}
resizeCanvas();
````

On my canvas whenever I draw while hovering over a button then moving my cursor back to the canvas causes me to draw without pressing until I press again. Could someone please tell me how to fix this glitch. This glitch occurs with my clear button, thickness slider, and my color changer. In addition how do I add something to stop drawing on the clear button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if the following change to the javascript will work for you -

When draw() is called by a Mouse Move event it won't check if painting is set to true anymore rather it will check the status of the Mouse Event to see if they are holding down the left click that way when you go off the canvas and hover over one of the buttons and come back onto the canvas it will check to see if you have the left click held down and draw if that's true

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sva26wym/) if it helps

You can see more about those which properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which)

```
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const color = document.querySelector("#color");
    const strokeWeight = document.querySelector("#strokeWeight");
    //variables
    const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear");
  
    let painting = false;
  
    function startPosition(e) {
      painting = true;
      draw(e);
    }
    function finishedPosition() {
      painting = false;
      ctx.beginPath();
    }
  
    function draw(e) {
      //if (!painting) return;
      if(e.which == 1){
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      }else{
      finishedPosition();
      }
      
    }
  
    function changeColor(e) {
      const color = e.target.value;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    }

    function changeStrokeWeight(e) {
        const strokeWeight = e.target.value;
        ctx.lineWidth = strokeWeight;
    }

  
    //Event listeners
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishedPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  
    color.addEventListener("input", changeColor);
    strokeWeight.addEventListener("input", changeStrokeWeight);
  
    //Buttons
    clearButton.addEventListener("click", clearCanvas);
  
    function clearCanvas() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
});
  
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
function resizeCanvas() {
    //Resizing
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
}
resizeCanvas();
```

Comment: Np glad to help! Accept as answer whenever you have a second, Thanks!

Comment: I am actually a beginner and I didn't know about the e.which property. Could you please explain it? Thanks. Also, what does the "1" represent in e.which == 1.

Comment: Sure, the 1 just represents that the left button was pressed down when the MouseMove event was fired there are a couple of different states that it can be in e.g 0: No button
1: Left button
2: Middle button (if present)
3: Right button, something worth noting is that if you are going to production with this it's recommended to use these https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button instead to check what button is pressed down. You can also check what browsers support those events at the bottom of those Mozilla pages if you need to support certain browsers

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.